# Limit of $ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(n \mod i)}}{n^2} $

Tags: limits, number-theory

I was playing with the function $ f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(n \mod i)} $. After looking at $ \frac{f(2n)}{f(n)}$ for some values it seemed quadratic, and I was wondering about the limit of $ \frac{f(n)}{n^2} $.

I tried to calculate that for big values.
I was able to find a [method](https://pastebin.com/Czc9je27) to calculating it in $ O(\sqrt{n}) $, and for $n = 10^{19}$, $f(n) = 17753296657588678168165249620624323219$, and after giving the first few digits to wolfram alpha it seems like it's $1 - \frac{\zeta(2)}2$ (I found it with smaller values, and since it also matches for bigger values it feels likely it's correct).

Is that correct? How can I prove that?

Comment: And yes, it is _my_ answer.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195325/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-remainders-of-n/342889

Answer (score 3):

Using the properties of floor function, it is evident that

$$
(n\mod i)=n-i\lfloor n/i\rfloor
$$

Consequently, we have

$$
\sum_{i\le n}(n\mod i)=n^2-\sum_{i\le n}i\lfloor n/i\rfloor
$$

To continue, all we need is to estimate the remaining sum:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i\le n}i\lfloor n/i\rfloor
&=\sum_{i\le n}i\sum_{j\le n/i}1=\sum_{ij\le n}i \\
&=\sum_{j\le n}\sum_{i\le n/j}i=\sum_{j\le n}\left[{n^2\over2j^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac nj\right)\right] \\
&={n^2\over2}\sum_{j\le n}{1\over j^2}+\mathcal O(n\log n)
\end{aligned}

Using the fact that $\sum_{j>n}j^{-2}=\mathcal O(1/n)$, we deduce

$$
\sum_{i\le n}(n\mod i)=\left(1-{\zeta(2)\over2}\right)n^2+\mathcal O(n\log n)
$$

Hope this can help you!